# Wrong task ordering in capistrano v3.2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, capistrano

I don't understand task ordering in capistrano. (Using 3.2 version)

**UPDATED example of code**

`test_ordering.cap` file contains:

```
namespace :test_ordering do

  desc 'Starting task'
  task :start_testing do
    puts 'This task must be in the middle'
  end

  desc 'First message'
  task :first_message do
    puts 'This task must fire first, before starting task'
  end

  desc 'Second message'
  task :second_message do
    puts 'This task must be the last'
  end

  before 'test_ordering:start_testing', 'test_ordering:first_message'
  after 'test_ordering:start_testing', 'test_ordering:second_message'
end
```

When I'm doing `bundle exec cap staging test_ordering:start_testing` it returns:

```
ruby 2.0.0p451 (2014-02-24 revision 45167) [i686-linux]
This task must be in the middle
This task must fire first, before starting task
This task must be the last
```

Why does 'before' fires after the 'prepare' task?
My environment uses Ruby 2.0.0p451, Rails 4.0.4, and Capistrano 3.2.

Comment: Just for the sake of trying - what happens if you change the _order of the tasks in the file_? meaning define `task :second do ... end` first in the file...

Comment: Please show how you have 'namespaced' :first and :second under thinking_sphinx.

Comment: Hey guys, I've updated the code. Now you can try it by your own.

Comment: PS. Reordering tasks doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Works for me:

```
Matt-Gibsons-iMac:captest matt$ cap -V
Capistrano Version: 3.2.1 (Rake Version: 10.1.0)
Matt-Gibsons-iMac:captest matt$ cap staging test_ordering:start_testing
This task must fire first, before starting task
This task must be in the middle
This task must be the last
```

All I did was `cap init`, paste your code into `/lib/capistrano/tasks/test_ordering.rake`, and run.

You say you're using a `.cap` file -- the [latest Capistrano prefers .rake files](https://github.com/capistrano/capistrano/issues/898), so combined with my correct result would make me think that you might be running across a bug in an old version of Capistrano.

Looking at the recent issues history, I'm guessing it's [this bug, fixed in 3.2.1](https://github.com/capistrano/capistrano/issues/1004) that you're hitting. Upgrade to 3.2.1 and your problem should disappear.

Comment: Brilliant! Thanks. For those who wants to rename `.cap` to `.rake` don't forget to edit `Capfile` for new extension.